# Stackdriver scheduled uptime check

Tags: scheduler, scheduling, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, uptime

I would like to run uptime checks using Stackdriver only when my google cloud instance is running (it is service that only runs a few hours every day). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Stackdriver uptime check run according to your check interval "**Check every**" field.

You can choose between 1, 5, 10, or 15 minutes. For example, choosing 5 minutes will cause each geographic location to attempt to reach your service once in every 5 minute period. Using the default six locations, and checking every 5 minutes, your service sees an average of 1.2 requests per minute. Checking every 1 minute, your service sees an average of 6 requests per minute.

See the documentation [Here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Hopefully they will implement this feature in a future release.

Comment: you can rise a feature request for your concern following this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com)